# iText footer alignment without tabbing

Tags: itext

is there a better way of doing this at the bottom?
The code at the bottom works but it is very cumbersome.
The tabbing is ok, but it would be great if there would be an other solution.

Thanks for help!

```
// Footer
    final Phrase footerPhraseDate = new Phrase();
    footerPhraseDate.add(new Chunk("23.01.2011", fontUnderlined10));
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(new Chunk("                 ", fontUnderlined10));
    footerPhraseDate.add(new Chunk("\n"));
    footerPhraseDate.add(new Chunk("Datum", fontNormal8));
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    footerPhraseDate.add(new Chunk("Date", fontNormal8));

    final Paragraph footerParagraphDate = new Paragraph();
    footerParagraphDate.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    footerParagraphDate.add(footerPhraseDate);
    footerParagraphDate.setSpacingBefore(40f);
    footerParagraphDate.setIndentationLeft(90f);
    document.add(footerParagraphDate);
```

Comment: You might want to try it with a table.

Comment: With a table I have a problem with underlining the chunks

Comment: What underlining problem?

Comment: I only want to underline the date and not the whole line.

Comment: That should be easy using tables, too.